# Getting 403 Forbidden Error without Proper Cookies in HTTP Headers | Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, http-headers, http-status-code-403

I'm facing an issue with web scraping on https://dexscreener.com. I've discovered that in order to receive a server response with a status code of 200, it's necessary to specify not only the user-agent but also valid cookies. I'm currently manually copying cookies from the Firefox browser. If I don't provide cookies, I receive a 403 error. My own cookies work only for 30 minutes after creation.
I need to find a way to bypass this because web scraping should happen automatically without manual cookie replacement.Thanks to everyone who joins the discussion. I would greatly appreciate it if you could assist me!

Here's my current code:

```py
import requests
url = "https://dexscreener.com"}
cookies = {"__cf_bm": "*my_cookies*"}
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "*my_user-agent*"
}
session = requests.Session()
session.cookies.update(cookies)
session.headers.update(headers)
response = session.get(url)
print(response)
```

Comment: use `requests.Session` so it updates cookies automatically

Comment: @Daviid, It doesn't work. When the cookies expire, it gives a 403 error, and I need to log in again in Firefox and copy new cookies every 30 minutes. Maybe I didn't write the code correctly. If you can, please provide the correct code.

Comment: Did you try to use session? If so update the question with the code you tried.

Comment: BTW I'm pretty sure your problem is not authentication but Cloudflare.

Comment: Updated code with session()

Comment: @Daviid, I also think it's because of Cloudflare. Are there any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try to get cookies from response and refresh it then it needed with new one

```
import requests


url = "https://dexscreener.com"


response = requests.get(url)
cookies = response.cookies
```

or use selenium to get cookies from web browser automatically

```
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
```

Comment: I've already tried to extract cookies using requests and then insert them into my request, but those cookies don't work, even if I specify the user-agent when extracting cookies. Only the cookies I manually copy from Firefox directly work.

Comment: it's strange for me work, another way use selenium to get cookie

Comment: Another fact is that I used Selenium before, and it was scraping properly. However, I don't want to open a browser, so I discarded this method. The code was slow at that time.